# Why does Python require for clauses in list comprehensions to be the wrong way around?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Behold two list comprehensions, each involving two for clauses. We see that if the for clauses are in the correct order, Python gets confused. But if they are the wrong way around, Python can handle it. Why?

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 11 2012, 07:15:24) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> [x + y for x in range(y) for y in range(4)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
>>> [x + y for y in range(4) for x in range(y)]
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

Comment: write `for`s in a comprehension just like you would write normal loops: outer first, inner next.

Comment: I can see that that is what Python requires. What I am asking is why it is that way.

Comment: You are thinking of it as "first loop, then second loop." Think of it as "outer loop, then inner loop"

Comment: What makes you say it's the wrong way around?

Comment: I avoid nested list-comps for exactly this reason ...

Comment: imho multiple clauses in a list comprehension is bad form ... It becomes much harder to read and maintain ...

Comment: delnan, I say it's the wrong way around because the list comprehension in the case of a single for clause is built by sticking the for clause after the body of the comprehension. If you iterate this construction you naturally end up with the outermost loop furthest to the right.

Comment: I think there are other problems when we introduce `if`s, so maybe to avoid confusion it is better to have this order.

Comment: @Hammerite I'm not saying there aren't reasons for doing it in the order you favor. But there are also reasons to do it the other way around (one has already been given multiple times: It matches the order of the equivalent `for:` loops). It's the "wrong" and "right" I have a problem with.

Comment: delnan, at the risk of seeming only to repeat what I said before: the syntax for LCs, with the for clause placed to the right, very much suggests to me that in going from a for loop to a list comprehension we have seen the for clause "jump over" the loop body to the RHS. It would follow from this that if we have nested for loops and perform this procedure one loop level at a time, we'll end up with the outermost "for" furthest to the right. The fact that it doesn't work like this causes a surprise; Python seems to be doing the wrong thing, going against the impression it gave originally.

Comment: There is also the fact that in the form I am calling "right", the number of loop variables decreases from left to right. In the furthest left part of the comprehension (`x + y`) there are two variables, x and y. In the second-furthest left part (`x + y for x in range(y)`) there is only one variable, y. Finally, in the list comprehension as a whole, there are no variables.

Comment: If you think of a list comprehension as moving the *body* of a normal `for`-loop and *nothing else*, this will make sense. The trouble you seem to be having is that you think that putting the body on the left means the loops progress "outward" from there. In fact, the logic behind the syntax is that the loop body is removed from the rightmost side and placed where the list would normally be initialized. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Then why move the loop body at all? Why not keep everything in the same order as it was originally?

Comment: The body was moved to emphasize the structure of the result items and because the BDFL (Guido) liked it that way. Remember, list comprehensions are meant as syntactic sugar for *very small simple cases* where a `for` loop plus explicit accumulator would be less clear. Normally Python idiom favors an explicit loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List comprehensions were first introduced into Python as syntactic sugar for this form:

```
L = []
for innerseq in seq:
    for item in innerseq:
        LOOPS
            if CONDITION:
                L.append(BODY)
```

This is transformed to:

```
[BODY for innerseq in seq for item in innerseq LOOPS if CONDITION]
```

To make the transformation more obvious, notice that the `for` expressions and the `if` condition occur in exactly the same order as they would in a normal `for`-loop. This is why the list comprehension uses the same order.

When you rewrite loops as a comprehension, the only thing that changes is the placement of the body of the loop (it moves to the front, where you would normally initialize your empty container). Everything else about the loop remains exactly the same.

The alternatives you prefer (your "right way") both seem *far* more confusing. Either we *just* reverse the order of the loops, or we reverse the order of *every* clause in the comprehension.  I.e., either:

```
[BODY LOOPS[::-1] for item in innerseq for innerseq in seq if CONDITION]
```

Or

```
[BODY if CONDITION LOOPS[::-1] for item in innerseq for innerseq in seq]
```

Either of these seem like an unnecessarily complicated transformation.

Also note that other languages use the same order for loops in their list comprehensions. Here is some Clojure:

```lisp
user=> ; using your suggested "right" order
user=> (for [x (range y) y (range 4)] (+ x y))
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: y in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1) 
user=> ; you need to use the same "wrong" order as Python
user=> (for [y (range 4) x (range y)] (+ x y))
(1 2 3 3 4 5)
```

This is the same as Python even though Clojure puts the "body" of the comprehension at the end.

If it helps, imagine that the `for` loops are arranged like the digits in a car odometer. The right-most loop spins the fastest.

Comment: In your clojure example, it would appear (I don't know Clojure) that neither loop uses the other loop's variable; it could surely work either way around, and in Python this would be the case too.

Comment: The order of evaluation is the same--left-to-right. I can change the Clojure example to use a defined variable, but it doesn't change the principle being illustrated here.

Comment: You suggest that either the order of the loops or the order of every clause should be reversed - I would say that the order of the for clauses should be reversed, with each conditional being placed to the right of the outermost for clause that makes sense. This mirrors set-builder notation in mathematics: we write {P(x) for x in X such that Q(x)}; we might write {P(x, y) for x in X such that Q(x, y) for y in Y such that R(y)}.

Comment: Python does not have a mathematical pedigree. In most programming languages, a var is evaluated or defined in the order it appears when the code is read from left to right. Having a specific special case in the language where vars came into existence in the *opposite* order of the order in which they are read would be *unwise*, especially for a language like Python which emphases readability and a minimum of surprises.

Comment: Also imagine you have a normal loop you are refactoring into a list-comprehension or vice-versa. If the loop items are reversed, this transformation becomes very complex (reshuffling clauses) vs just copy-pasting the body into a new position and adding some indentation.

Comment: BTW, changed the Clojure example to show interdependence and order of creation of the `x` and `y` vars in your original example.

Comment: I would like to note in passing that there's nothing wrong to me about the Clojure syntax, because the ... clauses? ... parts? ... in that are in a logical order. It's the fact that in Python just one part has been picked up and moved somewhere else that makes it not make sense.

Answer (score 5):

In

```
[x + y for x in range(y) for y in range(4)]
```

the `y` in `range(y)` is unknown at that place. Equivalent to:

```
for x in range(y):
    for y in range(4):
        # x + y
```

See [PEP-0202](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) for more information:

```
- The form [... for x... for y...] nests, with the last index
      varying fastest, just like nested for loops.
```

Comment: I can see that that is the case. What I'm asking is why that's the case. It would make more sense for the "outer" range (y) to be on the right, since we are sticking the for clauses on to the right.

Comment: and it is much more clear to use the nested for loops than the multiple for LC

Comment: Unless I missed something your link again explains the what, but not the why.

Answer (score 3):

This is an excellent question!

The answer is that, unlike most of Python, these nested comprehensions are written the way the interpreter wants to read them, not the way you'd like to write them.

The interpreter reads the comprehension right-to-left:

```
[(this is interpreted last) for (this is interpreted first)]
```

However, each clause is read left-to-right, so in `y in range(4) for x in range(y)` you have to explain what `y` is before you can `range(y)` out of it.

It's confusing because when you think of *nesting* the comprehension, you're think right-to-left.

Comment: That's not true that it "reads left to right". After all, even in the correct usage the `y` appears in `x + y` before it is defined in `for y in range(4)`.

Comment: Yeah, the interpreter evaluates comprehension from right to left - like many other languages.

Comment: @DavidRobinson -- You're right, but that's as close to an answer to the *WHY* question as you're going to get.  The other answers/comments may as well be "Because that's just how it is" as far as I can tell.

Comment: The interpreter only interprets the comprehension right-to-left.